# Bundle Identifier confusion

Tags: iphone

Bundle Identifier in info plist has my name as company name and then product name which is basically application name.

So my question is that when i enter Bundle Identifier in provisioning profile myname.appname it shows in red that please use alphabet characters or numbers only. Why is that. I don't have company domain name instead i have myname. So i m using myname.appname in Bundle Identifier it shows message in red.

Am i doing something wrong here.

Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

solved it. was using space in my name that is where the problem was.there should be no space if using name instead of company name. So basically myname.appname with no space in between